# linq to sql or LLBL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, orm, llblgenpro

I am starting big asp.net project but I could not decided LLbl or linq to sql. Can you help me? What is advantage or disadvantage of linq to sql and LLBL? Which one should I use?

---

Thank you for answers. I wanna ask one question. I will use it for big project. How is linq to sql and LLBL performance? Which one is faster?

Answer (score 2):

If your choices are L2S or EF and LLBL - Go with LLBL every day, all day, and sometimes at night. No joke.

LLBL has one of the most expressive Linq providers and incredible extensibility. The code is rock solid, unlike, cough... well you might know what I mean.

but let me tell you how i really feel about it.... lol..

Comment: Oh, and the customer support is like no other. If you find and confirm bug you can count on a build with a fix within days. I chit you not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Linq2SQL is that Microsoft is no longer developing Linq2SQL...

[Is LINQ to SQL Truly Dead](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/DLINQ-Future)? by Jonathan Allen for InfoQ.com

> Matt Warren describes [LINQ to SQL] as
>   something that "was never even
>   supposed to exist." Essentially, it
>   was just supposed to be stand-in to
>   help them develop LINQ until the real
>   ORM was ready.
>
> ...
>
> The scale of Entity Framework caused
>   it to miss the .NET 3.5/Visual Studio
>   2008 deadline. It was completed in
>   time for the unfortunately named ".NET
>   3.5 Service Pack 1", which was more like a major release than a service
>   pack.
>
> ...
>
> Developers do not like [ADO.NET Entity
>   Framework] because of the complexity.
>
> ...
>
> as of .NET 4.0, LINQ to Entities will
>   be the recommended data access
>   solution for LINQ to relational
>   scenarios.

If you are thinking about LLBL as an alternative... might not be such a bad idea but I personally prefer Linq2SQL because it gives you a lot more freedom to create what ever adhoc queries you need. But if you need more structure then LLBL may be a better alternative... But then you have the Microsoft not developing Linq2SQL in the future to contend with.

Have you looked at Linq2Entities as an alternative or even NHibernate... If you need more on this, just let me know or look up [linq 2 sql vs linq 2 entities](http://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enAU328AU328&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linq+2+sql+vs+linq+2+entities)...

Hope that helps.

Anthony

Comment: I disagree with the contents of the linked article and the contents of this answer.  LinqToSql is still around and will be for a while.  Entity Framework 1.0 has issues, but I would hardly list complexity in the top 5 issues.

Comment: I didn't say that LinqToSql was going anywhere... I was simply pointing out that Microsoft has made their position clear when it comes the future of LinqToSql and any more releases and that L2E is where they are putting all their eggs...

Comment: Microsoft has not made their position clear.  This is not true: "Microsoft is no longer developing Linq2SQL".  There was development done for LinqToSql in .NET 4.0 / VS 2010: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40 .  I do agree that Microsoft is recommending people use Entity Framework, not LinqToSql.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding which one to use depends.  You have not provided nearly enough information for us to help you decide.  Both products have drawbacks that may or may not affect you.  There are other .NET ORMs that may be a better fit, but you haven't made it clear why you rejected those.

You can read a lot more about .NET ORMs here:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)

Please provide more context around your question.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL is not dead. 
Microsoft does not deprecate it in .NET 4.0. 
We are working on [our implementation](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/linq.html) of LINQ to Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and this implementation is actively developed.